# How to set first three bytes of integer? in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I want to set first three bytes of an integer to 0 in C++. I tried this code, but my integer variable `a` is not changing, output is always -63. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int a = 4294967233;
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  for(int i = 0; i< 24; i++)
    {
        a |= (0 << (i+8));
        std::cout <<  a << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: `0` left-shifted by anything you want is still `0`, and ORing `0` still has no effect on the original value.

Comment: What do you call "first" bytes? Byte ordering depends on the endianness of your machine. Maybe the expression you're looking for is "most significant bytes."

Comment: `int` is not required to be large enough to hold 3 bytes; it can be 16 bits wide. On desktop systems it typically is 32 or 64, but portable code won't make that assumption.

Comment: @YSC Endianness **does not** matter in this case!

Comment: @black It's just about using the right word to be sure everyone understand the same thing. Look at JSF's answer ;)

Comment: @YSC What wording? Let `A = 0xAABB`, `A & 0xFF` will always yield `0xBB`, regardless of the platform.

Comment: @black I mean actual word: those with letters we build sentence with. Please take a second to re-read my first comment ;)

Comment: @black, your example will yield `0xBB` (the least significant byte of `A`) regardless of platform.  But in doing so, it is yielding either the **first** or **last** byte of `A` depending on the platform.  If you wanted **first** regardless of platform, see my answer.  I expect wair92 did not mean "first" and should have said what was meant.

Comment: @JSF Instead I strongly doubt the OP was referring to the very first byte, endianness-dependent, thus. First, it's much rarer to be needed; second, (s)he accepted soon's answer, which is not platform-dependent.

Comment: @black you are still missing the point.  The point is not that I think the OP meant "first" but that (s)he probably didn't mean "first".  Notice the perfectly reasonable speculation in the first comment by YSC that the meaning was "most significant".  That is what non programmers and beginner programmers would mean by "first".  You leap from "first" to "least significant" but is that leap correct?  Accepting an answer is less convincing when there is that much ambiguity.

Comment: @black I'm neither right nor wrong: I was asking OP for the right interpretation. Look how I _asked_ what was meant by "first," and how I said "*maybe* the expression..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use bitwise and (`&`) with a mask, there is no reason for loop:

```
a &= 0xFF000000; // Drops all but the third lowest byte
a &= 0x000000FF; // Drops all but the lowest byte
```

(Thanks to @JSF for the corrections)

As noted by @black, you may use [Digit separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Digit_separators) since C++14 in order to make your code more readable:

```
a &= 0xFF'00'00'00; // Drops all but the third lowest byte
a &= 0x00'00'00'FF; // Drops all but the lowest byte
```

Comment: You may find it easier to have `0xFF'00'00'00`.

Comment: Your first example drops all but the third lowest.  Your second drops all but the lowest.  The "three" in both your comments is an unjustified assumption.

Comment: If you really want to drop the "lowest three" that should be `a &=~ 0xFFFFFF;`, which assumes `a` has the same size as default integers of the platform.  If `a` is bigger, a cast is required, such as `a &=~ (unsigned long long)0xFFFFFF;`

Answer (score 2):

Years later, I've got an up for this answer and realized that it's an endianness dependent solution. It would not work on every platform. So I'm leaving it as a **wrong answer**.

**This is a misleading answer**:

> union also could be a choice
>
> ```
> union my_type{
>     int i;
>     unsigned int u;
>     ...
>     unsigned char bytes[4];
> };
> ...
> my_type t;
> t.u = 0xabcdefab;
> t.bytes[0] = 5; // t.u = 0x05cdefab
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You need `&=` instead of `|=`.

Comment: And now you're AND-ing 0. This is only half of an answer. And frankly, quite low-quality at that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean "first" not lowest, then take advantage of the fact that alias rules let char alias anything:

```
  int a = 4294967233;
  char* p=&a;
  ...
  p[0] = whatever you wanted there
  p[1] = whatever you wanted there
  p[2] = whatever you wanted there
```

Comment: This will be endianness-dependent, unlike in soon's answer, because you're operating on the byte layout in memory which is in fact platform-dependent.

Comment: Your comment implies a very different meaning of "first" than I have.  I guess English is that imprecise.  But I think my interpretation of the word "first" is more reasonable.  So my answer **unlike soon's answer** is not platform dependent.  Very likely, the OP did not actually mean "first", but meant something else, which is why I started my answer the way I did.